# Setting up Python's ArgumentParser with two mutually excluding flags where one flag has optional additional flags

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I would like to define the following using Python's ArgumentParser:

```
--mutually_exclusive_flag_A stringParameter

--mutually_exclusive_flag_B stringParameter
    --optional_b_flag_one
    --optional_b_flag_two
```

One can use either mutually_exclusive_flag_A or mutually_exclusive_flag_B, but not both.

If one uses mutually_exclusive_flag_B, then one can use optional_b_flag_one and optional_b_flag_two.

optional_b_flag_one and optional_b_flag_two are boolean flags.

I do see add_mutally_exclusive_group to handle selecting mutually_exclusive_flag_A or mutually_exclusive_flag_B. However, what I am not sure how to do is declare that if I use mutually_exclusive_flag_B, then optional_b_flag_one and optional_b_flag_two are valid flags.

It seems like I may be able to use the subparsers feature and turn mutually_exclusive_flag_A and mutually_exclusive_flag_B into commands.

What is my best option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argparse` can't handle that complex of a test.  Mutually exclusive groups can't be nested, and they don't handle other kinds of logic (only `xor`, not `and` and `or`).  I've explored such an expansion in a Python bug/issue, but it's not a trivial addition.

The best choice is to do your own testing after parsing.

The primary purpose of `argparse` is to figure out what your user wants.  Checking validity, and issuing a nice error message is a plus, but not central to the parsing task.

One of the problems with expanding this mechanism is write a meaningful usage message for general combinations.  Have you thought about how you'd explain this requirement to your users?